# Determing whether client device is mobiile or pc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to determine whether a client is using a mobile device and if it's not a mobile device then I want to record it as pc regardless of whether it's a laptop or desktop. Thus far I have managed to write code to determine if it's a mobile device but I am slightly confused as to how to determine whether it is a pc? navigator.platform will give me WIN32 and I don't think this will be accurate

```
var customizeForDevice = function(){
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var checker = {
          iphone: ua.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/),
          blackberry: ua.match(/BlackBerry/),
          android: ua.match(/Android/)
        };
        if (checker.android){
            $('.android-only').show();
        }
        else if (checker.iphone){
            $('.idevice-only').show();
        }
        else if (checker.blackberry){
            $('.berry-only').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.unknown-device').show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
   console.log('You are using a mobile device!');
}
else
{
   console.log('You are not using a mobile device!');
}
```

//jQuery.browser.mobile will return true if its a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find out which device accesses a website in a browser is not a trivial task. In your approach with 'navigator' you would have to create and maintain own mappings and mechanisms about what is considered 'client' or 'desktop'.
I would recommend using some existing library instead of writing something own.

[isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile) could be an interesting pick for this case.

`isMobile.phone` would here answer your question, if it's a mobile phone. It also offers the question for a tablet device: `isMobile.tablet`.